# ZF2: Attach event to another Controller's Action and get Service Locator

Tags: events, zend-framework2, config

I am new to Zend Framework 2. I have two modules 'A' and 'B'. I trigger an event in LoginController's LoginAction of "A" module. I want to attach LoginController's LoginAction or LoginController's testMe() method.

In "A" module's LoginController's LoginAction, I have written

```
$this->getEventManager()->trigger('checkme.post', null, array('user_id' => $userData->usydstudentid));
```

In Module.php of "B" module, in on Bootstrap method, I have given

```
$loginController = new B\Controller\LoginController();

$sharedEventManager->attach('A\Controller\LoginController', 'checkme.post', array($loginController, 'LoginAction'), 100);
```

In LoginController's LoginAction of "B" module, I can access data but I can not access service manager in order to get module' config. When I try to use

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
```

I get error

> Call to a member function get() on a non-object

In other words, I want to trigger an event from one controller's method and attach to another controller's method. After listening, getting data from that event, I want to get module's config. Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use events and controllers this way. Your controller from B isn't a controller, but you should put that one rather in a service layer.

Then, the service locator must be injected. If you do `$controller = new SomeController` this service locator is not injected. Thus, fetching any object from it will fail. What you should do is using the controller loader to get the controller.

So instead of this:

```
$loginController = new B\Controller\LoginController();

$sharedEventManager->attach('A\Controller\LoginController',
                            'checkme.post',
                            array($loginController, 'LoginAction'),
                            100);
```

You should write this:

```
// $sl is instance of Service Locator
// E.g. $sl = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
// Where $e is the event from the onBootstrap() method

$loader          = $sl->get('ControllerLoader');
$loginController = $loader->get('B\Controller\LoginController');

$sharedEventManager->attach('A\Controller\LoginController',
                            'checkme.post',
                            array($loginController, 'LoginAction'),
                            100);
```

But as said, triggering an action in a controller this way with events isn't realy a good way to do it. You better dispatch it with for example the controller plugin `Forward` or (as I said it before), remove the logic from the controller's LoginAction and locate it in a service class or something.

Comment: Thanks for kind reply. After creating $controller, will it replace $loginController in 

$sharedEventManager->attach('A\Controller\LoginController',
                            'checkme.post',
                            array($controller, 'LoginAction'),
                            100);  ?
Please also provide some links to study about approach of service or controller plugin.

Comment: You're right about the controller vs logincontroller. I fixed that. Re service layer: there is no real docs about this topic per se, but rather if you look at how services work (esp in combination with events) and what the goal is of a controller, you see the controller from module B is maps better on the ontology of a service layer than controller. A controller "just" handles the environment ($_GET, $_POST and $_SERVER) and utilises services/repositories/models/forms to accomplish its task. B's controller does not fit this description imho.

Comment: I am getting this error. 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for B\Controller\LoginController' in C:\wampp\www\Zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 495

Comment: What is the service name you have registered your controller? You should name your controller just like you did with the controller in module A. If you named the controller in your config, then you have to use that name in this `get()` call. See the "controllers" config (2nd code part) here: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html#create-a-route

Comment: Got it. it was like "B\Controller\Login". One more question, After attaching the event, It goes into LoginAction method. If I use $this to access other method in the same controller class like $this->getMe() then I am getting error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wampp\www\Zend2\module\B\src\B\Controller\LoginController.php on line 60"

Comment: @azeem I would create another question for that. I cannot give an answer with such little information in these small comment fields. :)

Comment: Here I have asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706045/zf2-using-this-when-not-in-object-context-when-accessing-other-method-inside-c