# ZF2: Using $this when not in object context When accessing other method inside controller

Tags: events, controller, zend-framework2

Based on reply from [ZF2: Attach event to another Controller's Action and get Service Locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696781/zf2-attach-event-to-another-controllers-action-and-get-service-locator/19700964?noredirect=1#comment29271287_19700964), I am attaching an event to a controller's action like this

```
$loader = $sl->get('ControllerLoader');
$loginController = $loader->get('B\Controller\LoginController');

$sharedEventManager->attach('A\Controller\LoginController',
                            'checkme.post',
                            array($loginController, 'loginAction'),
                            100);
```

When event fire, It goes inside loginAction of "B"'s controller. Inside loginAction when I try to call other method of B\LoginController, then I get an error of

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   C:\wampp\www\Zend2\module\B\src\B\Controller\LoginController.php
>   Blockquote
>   on line 60

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
<?php

namespace B\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Soap\Client;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function loginAction($e) {
       $user_id = $e->getParam('user_id');
       $config = $e->getParam('config');

       if($user_id){
            $client = $this->getSoapClient($config);
            $params = $this->enrolmentRequestParams($user_id);
            $response = $client->getEnrolment($params);
            $course_enrolment = $response->enrolment_list->value->course_enrolment_list->course_enrolment;
            $this->processEnrolmentData($course_enrolment);
       }
    }


    public function getSoapClient($config){
        $options = array(
                    'soap_version'=> $config['webservice_config']['soap_version'],
                    'location' => $config['webservice_config']['location']
                   );

        $wsdl = $config['webservice_config']['wsdl'];

        $client = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdl, $options);
        return $client;
    }

    public function processEnrolmentData($course_enrolment){

        foreach($course_enrolment as $ce){
                // some code here

            }

    }

    public function enrolmentLookUp($e){

      //some code here

    }

    public function enrolmentRequestParams($sid){
        //some code here
    }

    public function  emptyObject($theObject){
        $tmp = (array) $theObject;

        if(empty($tmp)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function validVal($uos){

        if(!empty($uos) && !is_null($uos) && isset($uos)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

   public function getSemesterNo($value){
        return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$value);
    }

}

?>
```

Please help in this regard.

Comment: can you post the loginConroller code too please

Comment: Maybe it is only a typo. Method names have lowercase first letters in ZF2 conventions. You wrote a capitalized `LoginAction` in your attach.

Comment: Updated with controller code and also changed "LoginAction" to "loginAction". Still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe im wrong here but is this good naming of path in module? C:\wampp\www\Zend2\module\ **B** \src\ **USydWebService** \Controller\LoginController.php should be C:\wampp\www\Zend2\module\ **B** \src\ **B** \Controller\LoginController.php

Comment: That was type when renaming the module name while posting question. Problem still exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an array as the callback, the class method is called statically (i.e. equivalent to you doing `LoginController::loginAction(e)`). There is no `$this`, because the function is not being called on an instance of the class.

It looks like most of the logic you have in the controller class shouldn't be in a controller at all. I'd suggest moving it to a separate class which you can then adjust to better handle static method calls.